# How can I open Push Notifications to test using Appium with C# for Android and iOS

Tags: c#, appium, browserstack

I have looked through the documents and I only see C# as todo. I have seen java and its `driver.openNotifications()`
When trying this with C# I get a message stating that Appium does not contain a definition for `openNotifications`
Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I am using a 3rd party system and I use there Real Devices for testing so I will not know and be able to provision devices before hand.

Comment: I do see the above in the  public const string OpenNotifications = "openNotifications"; github. BUt I still have the same problem from above.

Comment: I do not see it in my AppiumDriver package. I am using 3.14 it is the newest Nuget Pcakage for Appium I can find on my Visual Studio.